# Finding Max Value on Inner Join - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have a temp table, lets call it #order, within this table there are multiple records of order history with changes.

[image: #order table]

I'm looking to see the max value of the column `or_chgn` in which scales in the above example with all changes made to an order file.

However, when I write my query, the result I get is in error.

Query

```
SELECT * 
FROM t.#ORDER
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT OR_ORDN, max(OR_CHGN) OR_CHGN
    FROM t.#ORDER
    GROUP BY OR_ORDN
    ) d
ON t.OR_ORDN = d.OR_ORDN 
and t.OR_CHGN = d.OR_CHGN
```

Message:

> ```
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
>
> The multi-part identifier "t.OR_ORDN" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
>
> The multi-part identifier "t.OR_CHGN" could not be bound.
> ```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare alias `t` in the `from` clause of the outer query, so you can then refer to it in the `ON` clause of the `JOIN`.

Since it looks like your schema is called `t` already, I am changing the aliases to make things clearer:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t.#ORDER o  --> here
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT OR_ORDN, max(OR_CHGN) OR_CHGN
    FROM t.#ORDER
    GROUP BY OR_ORDN
) omax ON omax.OR_ORDN = o.OR_ORDN AND omax.OR_CHGN = o.OR_CHGN
```

Another commonly-used approach at this greatest-n-per-group problem is to use a correlated subquery, which somehow simplifies the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t.#ORDER o  
WHERE OR_CHGN = (
    SELECT MAX(o1.OR_CHGN) FROM t.#ORDER o1 WHERE o1.OR_ORDN = o.OR_ORDN
)
```

This query would take advantage of an index on `(OR_ORDN, OR_CHGN)`.

Comment: Ah, such an easily overlooked item, i didn't recognize my copy/paste and left that before the # on the row.

Thanks 
-Leo

Comment: interesting, ill be sure to reference this post if i have troubles in the future, the latter seems extremely efficient.